# Ayuda con comando subprocess.check_output

Tags: python

Tengo que hacer un programa que tome la lista de archivos de un directorio y guardarlos en un arreglo para despues ver si son archivos o carpetas.
tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess, os
array = subprocess.check_output(["ls","-a","/usr/bin/"])
for h in array:
    if os.path.isdir(h):
        print 'bandera1'
    else:
        print 'bandera2'
```

pero a la hora de hacer eso toma caracter por caracter de la variablle array, como podria hacer para que me tome la palabra completa correspondiente al nombre del archivo?

Answer (score 0):

Toma carácter por carácter porque el resultado de `check_output` es una cadena de texto (no un array) y la iteración de una cadena se realiza carácter a carácter.

Podrías partir dicha cadena en cada salto de línea, con lo que tendrías:

```
for h in array.split('\n'):
    ...
```

Pero mejor aún es que uses `os.listdir()`, que es mucho más limpio y directo, y además te devuelve directamente un array.

```
import os
path = '/usr/bin/'
for h in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, h)):
        ...
    else:
        ...
```

Fíjate en que usamos `os.path.join()` para reconstruir la ruta hasta el archivo (ya que `os.listdir()` no incluye la ruta en los resultados, lo cual sucede también en el `ls` de tu ejemplo).

Si adicionalmente necesitas recorrer los subdirectorios, suele ser más adecuado usar `os.walk()`, que además te da los listados de directorios y archivos ya separados en dos arrays diferentes (https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk).